# using environment variables in tmux.conf files

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

Is it possible to use an environment variable in a tmux.conf file? I am trying to set a default-path to an environment variable. Currently what I am trying is:

```
set -g default-path $MYVAR
```

further I would like to check if $MYVAR is set already so I could do:

```
if($MYVAR == "") set-environment -g MYVAR /somepath/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it looks like it is possible to expand shell variables in `.tmux.conf` file It looks like it's not required, but a good idea to quote them, esp. I was able to do this successfully with the status bar options just now.

```
# In ~/.tmux.conf:
set -g status_left "$MYVAR etc: "

$ export MYVAR="Shell stuff"
$ tmux
```

I don't know about any 'if' or other control structures in the config, but there might be.

Comment: I cant get this to work in a tmux script file.  I am sure $MYVAR is set, and I run the script and it fails. 
set -g default-path "$MYVAR"
split-window -h
it splits the window but default-path is not set to $MYVAR

Comment: ok i found where things are breaking down, if I set the environment variable before i run tmux then i can use it in my tmux.conf file.  If i set the environment variable, either in tmux.conf using set-environment or after i am in tmux then reload the tmux.conf it doenst use my new variables I have set.  Any idea why?

Comment: The shells you run inside tmux are child processes of tmux. Changing things inside those environments is not going to propogate back *up* the line to the tmux parent process. It only works the other way because tmux becomes a child of the shell you launched it from. I assume the config reload is similar in that it's launching a new child of the parent process.